# Trackpoint configuration is reset after boot in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: configuration, trackpoint

I am setting my the trackpoint configuration with the following program

[image]

After clicking the apply the configuration is set and everything works. The problem I have is that after a new start of the system the configuration is reset and I have to set it again. Is there a way to make this permanent?
Or does anyone know where this configuration is written so I can just overwrite it in a bash script on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found the solution, by looking at the source of the program the directory where the files are stored is the following in my case:

```
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/
```

And in this dir different configuration files with integer values can be found so the only thing that needs to be done is

```
echo xx | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/speed
echo xx | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/sensitivity
```

whereas `xx` needs to be between 0 and 250 (when its 0 the trackpoint does not work.

Here is a link for more explanation [link](https://gist.github.com/noromanba/11261595)