# Why I can not scroll by my thinkpad usb keyboard's trackpoint after I upgrade Ubuntu from 15.04 to 15.10

Tags: scrolling, trackpoint

Just after I upgrade the ubuntu from 15.04 to 15.10. I can not use my trackpoint + middle key to scroll web page. Actually it could move a little bit. How to fix it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652598/trackpoint-configuration-is-reset-after-boot-in-ubuntu-15-04?rq=1) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me. It seems installing the libinput input driver for X fixed my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

Restart X (logout/login) after installing.